# How to build a string regex pattern for number range from 0000-4095

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I want to build a regex to search number in a string (using c#) with range from 0000-4095. I use this string pattern:

```
string regex_pattern = (0?[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|{4}{0}[0-9]{0}|{4}{0}{9}[0-5]);
```

But i can not get success.

Can you please show me some hints?

Thanks

Comment: You do not have to post such questions on SO, since you may get all these regexps automatically at http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^([0123][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-5])$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T79wdd/3)

Sample

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Anu Viswan, your string pattern works fine. 

Btw, can you show me a hint to match for whole this data protocol like this:

"AP n nnnn nn\r\n" .In that string: n is number from 0-9; nnnn is number from 0000-4095; nn is from  0-99; \r\n is CRLF. And there are three space characters

Comment: Variations on a theme. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: This doesn't work for the entire range. Try for example 4089.
You should change the second group to 40[0-8][0-9]

Comment: @Chronicle Good Catch, have updated...Thanks

Comment: @Dominota you could use `^AP\s\d\s([0123][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-5])\s(\d\d)` with `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the multiples groups:

```
([0-4]0(([0-9][0-5])|([0-8][0-9])))|([0-3][0-9]{3})
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/slvIL2/4)